# 6 SPEAKERS one amp

Tags: speakers, impedance

I just joined stack exchange to ask this specific question.  I have 6 speakers.  All 6 are 8 ohm speakers.  There are 2 pairs (Speakers 1&2 are pair A and speakers 3&4 are pair B and then 2 other speakers, lets call them speakers 5&6)
Speakers 5&6 are two entirely different models, one is a bookshelf speaker and the other is an 8 inch speaker, but all 6 speakers are 8 ohm speakers.

I have a 2 ch 50 watt amp rated at 4-8 ohms.

I want to connect speakers 1&3 in series to the left channel, 2&4 in series to the right channel.  This would create 16 ohm loads on either channel correct?

Now...

I want to take speakers 5&6 and connect them in an interesting way... I want to connect the (+) terminal from the left channel and the (-) terminal from the right channel and connect speaker 5, then the (-) terminal from the left channel and the (+) from the right channel and connect speaker 6. This is what I usually do if I want a mono sound for a speaker, connect one lead from left and one from right channel.

What effect does this have on total impedance for the amp?

I've already asked everyone at work, and I am told there is no need to do this, but that is not what I am asking.  If there were no need then I would not be asking the question!

Comment: Putting 2 speakers in series gives 16ohms : outside the range for your amp, so don’t do that...

Comment: Please draw a diagram. Solar Mike has a point, it it outside of the amplifiers range but you will be hard pressed to find one which starts to oscillate and destroy itself at 16 ohm load. As for going below the 4 ohm mark, you are pushing more current than it's made for, but only if you play at clip. If you can spare some headroom, you will still be below the max current the amplifier can deliver.

Comment: It depends on the amp;  because some amp's speaker negative terminals are signal common, and some are an inverted signal of the positive terminal.